# jQuery: don't mouseout under some circumstances

Tags: jquery, image, hover, mouseover, caption

I've got a pretty basic question that I can't wrap my head around (possibly since it's 5 AM here). It can be simplified to the following:

HTML:

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="logo" />
<span class="caption">This is a caption</span>
```

JS:

```
$("img").mouseover(function() {
    $('.caption').show();
});

$("img").mouseout(function() {
    $('.caption').hide();
});
```

Using CSS, I positioned the caption on top of the image using the z-index property and absolute positioning. The problem is that the caption will disappear once it's hovered, then reappear again if the mouse is still moving, resulting in a blinking annoyance.

Obviously this is not meant to happen. Basically, the mouseover event shouldn't be called when the caption itself is hovered. Anyone got a fix?

Comment: you can put an `if` statement in your function...

Comment: figured that, but what would I put in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

HTML:

```
<div class="image_hover">
  <img src="image.jpg` alt="logo" />
  <span class="caption">This is a caption</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".image_hover").live({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).find('.caption').show();
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).find('.caption').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!